# Kibana is displaying blank page

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installated Elasticsearch 2.1.0 with kibana 4.3.0
Both services are showing active in the server but When i open the URL : http://IP:5601 it is showing blank page or more like "This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT"
Could anybody tell what could be the issue?

Comment: what is the IP of the sever ? Replace IP with real ip

Comment: The IP I am using is private (10.*.*.*)

Comment: I had the same when requesting the page with cURL. It's probably a different problem than you had, but I hope this helps others. When you get an empty page when using cURL you need to follow redirects like this: `curl -L http://localhost:5601`